# How to pronounce the letter "E" in French, and how to pronounce its name in the French alphabet song

Tags: prononciation, france

I am trying to figure out how to pronounce the name of the letter "e" in French for the last year.. like in this song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xuZxGirWQI

*How do they call the letter "e"?

How do I produce this sound?*

Until now I referred to "E" and "eu" like the same sounds.
I would pronounce the e in "je" and "ne" and "me" like this:
I am saying the i sound in the English word "bird"
then I puckered my lips as if I am saying the oo sound in the word "good"
the letter "e" seems to be the most important letter in French and I don't know how to pronounce it.

Comment: I've watched a few online tutorials on how to pronounce the [ə] sound, and I'd recommend [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z5b_jKkoiI). Be careful, it is a much shorter sound as in "bird", but lip movement is the same to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I would indeed describe the sound of E like "eu", but not like in the word bird. It would be more like a mix or the sound I the word bird and the first sound of the word "expect", so it's like "eu" but a bit higher than in the word bird.
I recommend you listen to French YouTubers, it's the best way to know how to pronounce stuff

How to prononce "je":

https://youtu.be/IsBDzm-GUEE

How to prononce "e":

https://youtu.be/FOeuvYUpPgQ

French channels I recommand (they speak of subject unrelated to the French language, but they have a nice way of speaking and articulating their words and sentences):

- Dr Nozman
- Poisson Fécond
- Astronogeek

Comment: Maybe you have some sources for pronunciation examples (dictionnary, website, youtube videos)?

Comment: thanks man, the e sounds that she makes in the video sounds like the letter "o" in the word "lock" with rounded lips.

Comment: It does come close

Comment: If that was the answer you were looking for, you can accept it as an answer. Else, you can tell me what other specifications you need.

Comment: "the sound of E like 'eu'" ...as in what?  Sorry, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

For an English speaker I'd say the "e" in je, me, le.

Sounds a lot like the "e" in a trailing **"er"** in Octob**er** ...

You just have to remove the "r", close the mouth a bit more, and shorten the syllabus.

And yeah, French language is a bit weird when it comes to spelling...

J**eu**x,  Mercr**e**di, ch**eu**v**eu**x ... sounds all the same closed **eu**

But : B**eu**rre, **œu**f, n**eu**f are a bit *open* and sounds more like "b**i**rd".

That being said, there are a lot of french accent, and people from north or south will close or open the **e** or the **o** depending on folklore.

Good luck !